# Using A SeT Property To Set Multiple Properties Of A Class Simultaneously In C#

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a very large list of objects and each object in the list has the following properties: ID, Name, Make, Model, Color, Price

I know that if I want to quickly locate an object in the list I can use an Indexer and search for the object using it's ID.

But once I locate the object how do I change more than one property at the same time?

I thought about returning the MyClass Object in the get property of the Indexer so that I have access to all of its properties. However, I don't know what to do in the set property of the Indexer to make it work. Below is my code

```
public MyClass this[int id]
{
  get {return myObjectList.FirstOrDefault(item => item.ID == id);} 
  set {// something = value;}
}
```

Comment: What kind of enumerable is 'myObjectList'? Knowing that will change the set of options that you have.

Comment: is there a major!!! requirement for not know stuff at run time? in other words is there a real requirement to work with unknown objects... i.e at run time the code wont know anything about what its working with. if not then why are you making this WAY more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @Hans of course my class represents a collection, as I stated above I have a large list of objects and that list can be filled with data from any where. The class MyClass has properties I listed above and then I have another class that creates a list of MyClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But once I locate the object how do I change more than one properties at the same time?

It looks like you want to do something like

```
List[4] = {Name = "name", 
           Make = "make", 
           Model = "model", 
           Color = "color", 
           Price = "price
          };
```

Which is not possible in C#.  There's no syntax to set multiple properties of an existing object simultaneously. You can create a *new* object and *replace* the one in the list:

```
List[4] = new MyClass {
           Name = "name", 
           Make = "make", 
           Model = "model", 
           Color = "color", 
           Price = "price
          };
```

But that's creating a *new* object, not modifying an *existing* one.

The only way to set multiple properties is with individual `set`s:

```
MyClass obj = List[4];
obj.Name = "name";
obj.Make = "make";
obj.Model = "model"; 
ojb.Color = "color"; 
obj.Price = "price";
```

Note that this does not involve the setter of the index property at all.  It's not uncommon for collections to have a get-only indexer so that the list itself cannot be mutated through the indexer, although the properties of the objects inside can.

Comment: +1, but I'd like to add that just because the index property doesn't have a setter does not guarantee the list cannot be mutated! The rest of the list implementation needs to also not let you mutate it.

Comment: Your solution definitely works, thanks. stuartd's suggestion to forgo the setter also works but that confuses me since it allows me to set values of my objects without using the setter

Comment: @irreal That's what I meant, but I've clarified the last statement to be more specific.

Comment: @EternalCuriosity Because in that case you're using the setter of the _object_ not the _collection__.  The index setter for the collection only affects _what value is placed at that index_.  Think of the collection as a notebook that contains sheets of paper.  If you write on one of the sheets of paper, you're changing the _paper_, not the _notebook_.  The note book contains the exact same sheets of paper (metaphysically speaking). If you _took out_ a piece of paper and replaced it with a _different_ one, _then_ you'd be changing the notebook.